# RestSharpv107, ClientCertificate authentication broken in Azure. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, restsharp

I am using client certificate authentication for accessing a third party API. It was working fine till RestSharp 106.

When upgraded to v107/108, certificate authentication broke after deploying the app to Azure App Service. The application is working well on dev machines.

Following error appears -

```
HttpStatusCode: 0 (0) System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Error while calling API ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

My code for attaching certificate is (certificate is stored as base64 in settings)-

```
var x509 = new X509Certificate2();
x509.Import(certificateBytes, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
certificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection { x509 };

var options = new RestClientOptions(new Uri(serverBaseUrl))
            {
                MaxTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds,
            };

if (certificateCollection != null)
{
    options.ClientCertificates = certificateCollection;
}

var client = new RestClient(options);
```

What I have checked till now -

Correct API is being called. (logged using HttpTracer)
Correct Certificate is being used. (logged before API call from client. -

```
client.Options.ClientCertificates[0]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Update :

Tried Kevin's solution on KUDU using powershell, here is my code.

```
$Cert = new-object security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2
$cacertstr='base64stringofcertificate'
$bytes =[System.Convert]::FromBase64String($certstr)
$cert.Import($bytes,'certpassword',[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
$collection = New-Object security.cryptography.x509certificates.X509Certificate2Collection($cert)
$bytes =    [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($cacertstr)
$cert.Import($bytes)
$collection.Add($cert);
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("header1", "value1")
$headers.Add("header2", "value2")
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://url' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Certificate $cert
```

Same error

> Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS > secure channel.

Comment: RestSharp does nothing more than pass the certificates collection to the `HttpClient` instance, which is then used to make the requests https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/8fdbb4486322eb297220eae78b4e4150125490d1/src/RestSharp/RestClient.cs#L152-L155. Do you see anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue, and the same error message, but with RestSharp version 106...

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

We then tried with a pure `HttpClient` the same error occurred, which excluded a problem with RestSharp itself.

After months of investigations, including packets captures from Azure, we discovered that our requests were not even going out from the Azure infrastructure. HELLO packets were not found in our traces, proving nothing was getting out from Azure.

We contacted Azure's support team and found out what was the problem:
**In Azure, all requests carrying an attached TLS certificate are BLOCKED by default.**

You need to add a property in your App Service settings, `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` which specifies which TLS thumbprints you allow!
Mind you, this is effective for **outgoing** requests as well!
And even for certificates you manage yourself without using any of Azure certificates feature thing!

This is absolute nonsense!
I am right now arguing with the poor support guy that this is a backward behavior from Azure. My expectation as a Azure user, is that nothing should be blocked by default unless I do make some settings change myself!
Especially not outgoing requests!
Anyway.

All of this is documented there:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#make-the-certificate-accessible

Adding a new property `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES=*` solved our issue.
RestSharp or HttpClient both worked fine in the end.

Comment: I actually tried something similar, by adding the exact thumbprint of certificate I am using but it was not working. Tried with your method of accept all "*", still having same issue. I am testing with KUDU Powershell right now.

Comment: This solved the issue, KUDU process is probably not using the same settings and it still not able to connect the endpoint using PowerShell.